# Line spacing with scandinavian letters

Tags: line-spacing

Example tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Ylim\"{a}\"{a}r\"{a}isi\"{a} suodatuksia ja ikkunointeja ei tarvita, jos menetelm\"{a} pystyy itsess\"{a}\"{a}n erottelemaan ilmi\"{o}n ep\"{a}jatkuvuuskohdat, kuten syd\"{a}men kammion yht\"{a}kkisen liian aikaisen supistuksen tai syd\"{a}nl\"{a}p\"{a}n tukirakenteen pett\"{a}misen nestevirtausta vastaan.
\end{document}
```

which is seen as

[image]

The problem is that some sentences go over the line width like **pettämisen**.
The problem seems to be with words which has letters `\"{a}`.

**How can you cause normal cutting of words to new lines with sentences of having A with dots?**

Comment: this is more "line breaking" than "line spacing".  "line spacing" is usually understood to concern the vertical spacing between lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The text looks like Finnish. You have to load `babel` for getting correct hyphenation:

```
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
```

but also

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to get hyphenation points also past the accented letters.

With `inputenc` you can also type directly the accented letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\noindent taa siihen. % just to emulate your image
Ylim\"{a}\"{a}r\"{a}isi\"{a} suodatuksia ja ikkunointeja ei tarvita, jos menetelm\"{a} pystyy
itsess\"{a}\"{a}n erottelemaan ilmi\"{o}n ep\"{a}jatkuvuuskohdat, kuten syd\"{a}men kammion
yht\"{a}kkisen liian aikaisen supistuksen tai syd\"{a}nl\"{a}p\"{a}n tukirakenteen pett\"{a}misen
nestevirtausta vastaan.

\bigskip

\noindent taa siihen.
Ylimääräisiä suodatuksia ja ikkunointeja ei tarvita, jos menetelmä pystyy
itsessään erottelemaan ilmiön epäjatkuvuuskohdat, kuten sydämen kammion
yhtäkkisen liian aikaisen supistuksen tai sydänläpän tukirakenteen pettämisen
nestevirtausta vastaan.

\end{document}
```

[image]